# How to open MacOs text file correctly on Win?

Tags: windows, macos, text, character-encoding

How to convert Mac text files into Win text files and vice versa?

up to now I didn't know that MacOS and Win text files are different.
I am not talking about the newline characters: CR for MacOS, LF for Unix, and CR/LF for win.

Apparently, there are more differences when it comes to special characters, like Umlauts etc.
I got a text file created on a Mac, 
if I open this under Win with Notepad++, it tells me Macintosh ANSI, however,

ö becomes š

ä becomes Š

ü becomes Ÿ ...

with Notepad++, I tried all kinds of codings, Windows 1252-1 or ISO-8859, UTF-8, ...
As I learned, there seems to be a MacOS Roman encoding... which Notepad++, apparently does not understand.
When I might in the end somehow manage to open and edit the Mac text files correctly, I guess it might be best if I save them as UTF-8 for a further exchange between OS-systems hopfully without problems.

My question: how can I read Mac (encoded) text files properly unter Win?

(NB: sending the files to somebody with a Mac and asking him to save them as UTF-8, I wouldn't consider as a practical solution).

Comment: How are these files being created? How old are they? Mac OS Roman has been obsolete since the mid-2000s.

Comment: OS X/macOS hasn't used CR for quite some time now, it's been using LF for more then 10 years that I can remember.

Comment: @duskwuff these files are created by an audio transcription software, which is (as you say) not "up to date" concerning the encoding when exporting to text. Somebody with a Mac used BBEdit to detect that it is MacOS Roman encoded and could save it as UTF8. However, for me, it's probably very unlikely that any Windows software will detect an old, obsolete Mac encoding, isn't it?!

Comment: MacOS Roman, according to Wikipedia, is Code Page 10000. This [is supported on the .Net framework as text encoding "macintosh"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings(v=vs.110).aspx), so it should be peanuts to write a C# or VB program to convert it. This question is somewhat lacking the programmatic angle required for StackOverflow though.

Comment: Note, text encoding without bitwise requirements or specific identifying bytes can't really be detected, except heuristically. If in an encoding, any byte value from 0 to 255 maps to a character (as is the case for most pure 8-bit encodings), no data is ever "wrong" for that encoding, from a computer's point of view. And I don't know _any_ text editors that contain dictionaries of a few dozen languages just to detect what valid _words_ might be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nyerguds, well I hoped that there was a simple checkbox or list of codes in some program. But I couldn't find any so far...
However, there seems to be a programmatic solution...

```
# MacOSRoman2UTF8.py
import codecs, sys

# enter filename without .txt
fname = sys.argv[1]

with codecs.open(fname+'.txt', 'r', encoding='macroman') as file_in:
    file_content = file_in.read()

with codecs.open(fname+'_utf8.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    file_out.write(file_content)
```